# how to convert ISearchResponse<ExpandoObject> to IEnumerable<AbstractAssetCSVExport> in c#

Tags: c#

```
int total = 10000;
ISearchResponse<ExpandoObject> elasticResponse = await
client.Current.SearchAsync<ExpandoObject>(s =>
    s.Type(ElasticFactory.ElasticType.Asset.ToString())
     .Query(e => queryc)
     .Sort(sd => sort)
     .Size(total));

IEnumerable<AssetCSVExport> result = elasticResponse;
return result;
```

When I convert `Expandobject` to `IEnumerable` that time give conversion error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Nest.IHit<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>>`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PDX.Entities.V1.AssetCSVExport>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Give me a solution for this problem.....

Comment: Of course, `ExpandoObject` and `AssetCSVExport` are not the same type and probably can't cast to each other. you should use `Select()` to select the properties from `ExpandoObject` into `AssetCSVExport`. in order to get a full answer pls write down the `ExpandoObject` class and `AssetCSVExport` class

Comment: Why are you using ExpandoObject? I don't see any need for this.